# Replacing foreign key with related data in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a Cakephp application which is using containable to allow me to fetch associated data easily. Now this works great and does pull down all the data I'm looking for. The problem is it creates a sibling of the primary model instead of nesting the related data inside. I've included below what the current query is returning vs what I would like returned.

Ex of current:

```
{
    'Product' :
    {
        'id':321
        'name':'product name'
        'store_id':123
    },
    'Store' :
    {
        'id':123
        'name':'store name'
    }
}
```

Ex of desired:

```
{
    'Product' :
    {
        'id':321
        'name':'product name'
        'store': {
            'id':123,
            'name':'store name'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I Read you post 3 time, And still im not exsactly sure of what your asking,.

Comment: He wan'ts to change the structure of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating my own helper that will be generic enough to use on all types of data. This will search through the primary result and look for an _id key and then look for a model matching that id to combine.

```
<?php
App::uses('AppHelper', 'View/Helper');

class DataMapperHelper extends AppHelper {

    public function combineMultipleResults($dataArray) {
        return Hash::map($dataArray, "{n}", array($this, 'combineResults'));
    }

    public function combineResults($dataArray) {
        reset($dataArray);
        $primaryKey = key($dataArray);

        foreach ($dataArray[$primaryKey] as $key => $value) {
            if(preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]+_id/", $key) == 1) {

                $newKey = str_replace("_id", "", $key);
                $linkedDataKey = ucfirst($newKey);

                $dataArray[$primaryKey][$newKey] = $dataArray[$linkedDataKey];

                unset($dataArray[$primaryKey][$key]);
                unset($dataArray[$linkedDataKey]);
            }

        }

        return $dataArray[$primaryKey];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CakePHP's afterFind method of models:

```
class Product extends AppModel{
    function afterFind($results,$primaryKey){
        unset($results['Product']['store_id']);
        $results['Product']['store'] = $results['Store'];
        return $results;
    }
}
```

Note that the `$results` parameter which is being passed to the method, is the array that `find`returns by default, and the array that we return in the `afterFind` method is the array that `find` will return...

Comment: The afterFind() callback is not a good idea in this case except you want the result to be modified all time and every where. Also you would need to check if the associated model data is available before changing the structure. Also, you're not using the Model::$alias property which can result in notices and cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

The `afterFind()` callback is not a good idea in this case except you want the result to be modified *all time and every where*. Also you would need to check if the associated model data is available before changing the structure.

Read these two links:

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-a-data-view-with-view-files

Serialize your view variables and use a json view and change the data as you need there.

Example taken from the book:

```
// Controller code
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $this->set(compact('posts', 'comments'));
    }
}

// View code - app/View/Posts/json/index.ctp
foreach ($posts as &$post) {
    unset($post['Post']['generated_html']);
    // MODIFY YOUR DATA HERE AS NEEDED
}
echo json_encode(compact('posts', 'comments'));
```

Don't forget to set extension routing up and to use the RequestHandlerComponent. Read the links I provided, they explain it very well.